# How to convert .NET Date to Java Date

Tags: java, .net, date, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need a method to convert .NET Date in Java Date, currently if I try to convert this date retrieved from SharePoint 2010 with json:

```
/Date(-2209161600000)/
```

CONVERSION TEST:

```
String input = "/Date(-2209161600000)/";
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(input.substring(6,input.length()-2)));
```

I obtain:

**Sat Dec 30 01:00:00 CET 1899**

What is the current way in order to convert the .net date? What are the long milliseconds to add (or subtract) in order to obtain the java milliseconds?

Comment: Well, what date is it supposed to be? Seeing how it's a **negative** timestamp, a time in the past doesn't seem terribly wrongas a result - it's possible the data in Sharepoint is wrong to begin with. (It looks to me like it's midnight, Jan 1st, 1900 – i.e. 00-01-01 00:00, shifted to a different timezone.)

Comment: well I would serialize the .net date into some standard datetime representation, like ISO-8601, and from there you can use it in any other application/language etc.

Comment: @millimoose : Yes, correct, I've verified on SHarepoint and the date is wrong: 1899-12-30T00:00:00 ...so the conversion is correct!! I thought that something change between Unix and .Net....